# How to get the max value id from sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I need to get a max (Amount) value of each Account from the below table

```
ID   Account   Amount
1     rx00      100
2     rx00      200
3     rx00      100
4     vxtt       50
5     vxtt       70
6     vxtt       80
```

I need a result table as

```
ID   Account   Amount
2     rx00      200
6     vxtt       80
```

Please advise to the above result

Comment: _"I need to get a max (Amount) value"_ is different to your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`ROW_NUMBER`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) for this:

```
SELECT ID, Account, Amount
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Account, Amount,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account 
                            ORDER BY Amount DESC) AS rn
  FROM mytable) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

If you have ties, i.e. more than one records sharing the same maximum `Amount` value and you want to return all these records, then use [**`RANK`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte
as
(
select id,account,amount
,row_number () over (partition by account order by amount desc) as rn
from
table
)
select * from cte where rn=1
```

In above Code, a unique <kbd>[RowNumber](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)</kbd> is assigned for every value Partitioned by account and amount (values sorted in desc order of amount).since we cant directly select Row_number or any calculated value in where clause.I used a Virtual table

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Explaining RowNumber and Partition is beyond the scope of Post.but le me add few points

Comment: Do not see rn column in cte..?

Comment: Thank you .Edited Now.It was a Typo in rush to answer first :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **row_number** to get the desired result.

```
    DECLARE @table TABLE 
    (ID int, Account varchar(10),Amount int)

    INSERT INTO @table
    (ID,Account,Amount)
    VALUES
    (1,'rx00',100),
    (2,'rx00',200),
    (3,'rx00',100),
    (4,'vxtt',50),
    (5,'vxtt',70),
    (6,'vxtt',80)

   SELECT ID, Account, Amount
    FROM (
      SELECT ID, Account, Amount,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Account 
                                ORDER BY Amount DESC) AS rnk
      FROM @table) AS t
    WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

This will be the output:

```
ID  Account Amount
2   rx00    200
6   vxtt    80
```

If you don't need the ID column in the result set , you can use the below Query.

```
    SELECT Account,max(Amount)  AS Amount FROM @table t
    GROUP BY Account
```

This will be the output:

```
Account Amount 
rx00    200
vxtt    80
```